# Print array in c with string concatenation without last element

Tags: c, arrays

I am new to C and programming. I am trying to print an array separated by comma. But don't wish to print the last comma element. Here is my code so far

```
void p_array(const int array[], const int s) {
  for(int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
    printf("%i, ",array[i]);
  }
}
```

I am getting the array printed as

```
1, 2, 3, 4,
```

Whereas I dont wish to have the last element of comma printed. I know I am doing something fundamental wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
  if(i)
    printf(", ");
  printf("%i",array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
printf("%i%s", array[i], i==s-1 ? "" : ", ");
```

An alternative is to have the loop go one less iteration, and the print out the last element w/ a `printf` after the loop.